# Why can't I "PUT" data on JSONPlaceholder through Postman?

Tags: postman, jsonplaceholder

I am trying to put data on [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) through Postman, as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

But I could not find that data on [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)..

Did I do anything wrong or did the website just ignored my `PUT` request silently?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JSONPlaceholder Guide](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) under "Creating a Resource".

You will find a note that states:

> Important: resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if.

Your request works (Status Code: 201) but the resource is not actually created.

Answer (score 0):

JSONPlaceholder Guide
Put Method
Important: resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).